# Android BroadcastReceiver application doesn't die when application is closed

Tags: android, sms

I am attempting to make an application that reads text messages. The application works fine, when I get a text message, the message is displayed in a toast along with the phone number. The problem is, even with the application closed, ie not in the foreground, it still shows the toast when I get a text message. I have used a task killer application, and it still shows the toast. The only way to not show the toast is to unistall the application. I am using this website as a tutorial

> http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

I have done everything in the tutorial except for the encryption.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the correct behavior actully. Every time you get a message, the system sends a SMS broadcast. Since your application declares in it's manifest that it wants to receive such broadcasts, a new instance of your BroadcastReceiver will be created and executed every time.

If you want to execute the receiver only at certain times *(in this case when your app is in the foreground)*, you have to register and unregister it dynamically in code instead of the manifest by using [`Context.registerReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) and [`Context.unregisterReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29).

**How to do this exactly?**

Here's a short example. I'll assume that you have written your own class that extends BroadcastReceiver and handles stuff in `onReceive()`. The name of this class in this example is `SmsReceiver`, like in the linked tutorial.

Our goal is to receive broadcasts only when one activity is in the foreground, which means you should also have one class that extends Activity and displays UI like a normal app.

First of all we need an actual instance of the receiver as a class member. Add something like this to your activity class:

```
private SmsReceiver smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
```

*Sidenote:* That's actually one of the main differences between registering in the manifest and in code:

- In code you create a receiver instance by yourself
- When registered in the manifest, the system generates the instances for you in the background

Alright, great. Now we just have to register and unregister this receiver when the activity comes into the foreground and goes out of it. Have a look at the diagram in the [Activity class doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), the framework methods called in these events are `onResume()` and `onPause()`.

Add the following lines to your `onResume()` method:

```
@Override 
public void onResume() {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
}
```

What we did here is actually pretty simple. It's the code-equivalent of the manifests `<receiver />` tag. We created an intent filter with a broadcast that we like to receive and register our receiver with it.

The next step is to unregister in `onPause()`. Again, either add this line or create `onPause()` if you have not yet.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
}
```

Pretty straightforward - take our receiver instance and unregister it when the app is about to go into the background. And that's all the magic, everything should work as intended. **Don't forget** to delete the whole `<receiver />` tag in your manifest though, when you work with your existing code. Otherwise you would register your receiver in two ways.

Comment: So I am trying to implement what you suggested, but I am a little confused. Where do I put the registerReceiver, how do I use it properly, ie what is the code example. Is there an example you can link me to? I have this, but it causes a crash                BroadcastReceiver BR = null;
IntentFilter filter = null;
        
registerReceiver(BR, filter);

Comment: @ChrisSippel You can't register with `null` objects like this. I added a short guide to my answer.

Comment: So I finally go around to do thing properly, with the holidays and school, I've been busy. So I am really happy to say that it works, and that I am soo thankful to you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a `toast` as a sort of system notification. So it will display regardless of whether any `Activity` is in the foreground. Also, when you extend `BroadcastReceiver`, your class will still receive the intents as long as your process is alive. A `BroadcastReceiver` is not tied to any foreground `Activity`.

Comment: My hope was to shut down/stop the BroadcastReceiver when ever the application is not in the foreground. The toast is just a way for me to see what is happening.