# Android BroadcastReceiver is not working when application is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to write a service that will be triggered when a new app is installed. First of all, I think I need a broadcast receiver. The broadcast receiver does not work when the application is closed. I'm trying on Android 7.0 and 8.1

What am I doing wrong?

I tried this solution: 
[Android Broadcast Receiver is not working in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224341/android-broadcast-receiver-is-not-working-in-background)

And this solution:
[Android BroadcastReceiver application doesn't die when application is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584445/android-broadcastreceiver-application-doesnt-die-when-application-is-closed)

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

**My BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class IsPackageAdded extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean isAdded = false;
    public static boolean isRemoved = false;
    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "IsPackageAdded";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {
        this.context = paramContext;
        if (paramIntent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            isRemoved = true;
            String packageName = paramIntent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
            Log.d(TAG,"Successfully uninstalled: " + packageName);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully uninstalled: "+packageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        while (!paramIntent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
            return;
        }
        String packageName = paramIntent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
        Log.d(TAG,"Successfully installed: " + packageName);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully installed: "+packageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        isAdded = true;
    }
}
```

**My Manifest**

```xml
<application>
...
    <receiver
        android:name="com.sdatam.catcher.classes.IsPackageAdded"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
</application>
```

Another article says I should add this line in Manifest:

```xml
android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_ADDED"
```

Comment: Those broadcasts are not sent to manifest-registered receivers on Android 8.0 and higher. Also, that permission does not exist on Android 8.0+, AFAICT.

Comment: Thank you. So how can I do this in lower versions? I also tried it on Android 7.0.

Comment: Well, for starters, you get rid of that `while` loop. Your `Intent` will not change, so that will loop forever, or until Android terminates your process for tying up the main application thread.

Comment: My fault. I think I hurried to write a question. I tried to do this work with the service. I tried the receivers and services on another device with Android 7.0 and emulator. It's worked. I think there is a problem with my phone.  My phone is Casper Via F2 - Android 7.0. Some time after closing the application, logcat returns such a warning. 

`2020-03-05 09:32:00.130 1116-2356/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.catcher/.classes.AutoScanService in 1000ms`